# What does mean this sentence? "the sweep of his arm took in most of Main Street"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"the sweep of his arm took in most of Main Street"

What does this "sweep of his arm" mean?

Comment: Where is that from? What is the context? Is that the entire sentence?

Comment: He waved his arm to indicate most of Main Street that he could see. 'Take in' can mean 'include'.

Comment: The "sweep of an arm" is a gesture, i.e. the movement of an arm/hand when talking.

Comment: @Joachim  this is a example sentence for phrasal verb take in meaning   .                                
  take in
phrasal verb of take
1.
include or encompass something.
"the sweep of his arm took in most of Main Street"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you so much

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you so much